# How to change header color if the user reach an id? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

https://www.onepeloton.com/ I would like to create a similar header like this.

Right now I created a header and a sticky class. If I scroll down the header will be transparent, but I would like to make it to not transparent, if I reach a div with an ID.

```
header {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #F9E3E5;
}
header.sticky {
    background: #F9E3E5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(249,227,229, 0.0), rgba(249,227,229, 0.0));
}

HTML:
<header>
<a id="#1">1st</a>
<a id="#2">2nd</a>
</header>
<section>
<a id="#3">3rd</a>
</section>
<section>
<a id="#4">4th</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! You will need to post more code than just the CSS so we can have a look. Check out [reprex]. This is just too little to gone on...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp look at here

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
            var top1 = $('#header').offset().top
            var top2 = $('#2').offset().top;
            var top3 = $('#3').offset().top;
            $(document).scroll(function() {
            var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (scrollPos >= top2 && scrollPos < top3) {
                $('header').css('background-color', '#F9E3E5');
            } else if( scrollPos == 0) {
                $('header').css('background-color', '#fff');
            }
            });
</script>
```